# Meaning of "Back on their heels"

Tags: idiom-meaning

In a townhall meeting, President Obama used the expression of "being back on heels":

> Now, it's no secret that unions have been back on their heels a little
>   bit over the last several decades. Part of that has to do with the
>   globalization...

[C-SPAN video](http://www.c-span.org/video/?320014-2/president-obama-economy) at timestamp 00:34:03.

While I am aware of other idioms involving "heels", I have not heard this one before, and an online search did not reveal much. [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/set-or-rock-someone-back-on-their-heels) says that "set (or rock) someone back on their heels" means "astonish or disconcert someone" but it's not the meaning intended in the speech. I would appreciate help here.

Comment: I'd say it's either ignorance or deliberate obfuscation, but that what he *meant* was the unions have been [*on the back **foot***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/on-the-back-foot) (BrE: *outmanoeuvred by a competitor or opponent; at a disadvantage*). Here's [another instance of this non-standard usage](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=g1n6Eb6tMqkC&q=%22been+back+on+their+heels%22&dq=%22been+back+on+their+heels%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kFjGVM_yM6XV7Aaa8oDQDA&redir_esc=y), where it clearly means *idle, resting on one's laurels, kicking one's heels*.

Comment: @Sabuncu: I'm not convinced this is a valid question for ELU. The expression only occurs three times in the whole of Google Books, and the only one I actually *looked* at is different to your example anyway. It's not an idiomatically standard usage, so any guesses as to *intended* meaning are essentially going to be based on full context plus personal opinion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But it wasn't some joker on the street who uttered it, it was the president of the US.

Comment: @Sabuncu: Politicians who get to the top in democracies are almost invariably real experts in being *vague*, in such a way as to maximise the number of potential voters who believe that what was meant corresponds to what they already believe. So an anti-unionist might believe Obama is saying the unions have sat around doing nothing for decades, while a pro-unionist hears exactly the same speech, but believes Obama is expressing sympathy for unions which have been unreasonably disadvantaged by hostile policies. Net result - they both vote for Obama (as was always intended).

Comment: It means being hit, or attacked, or being defensive. I think the term comes from boxing, where they normally lean forward with the weight on their toes. If they are being hit hard, it knocks them backwards so their weight is on their heels. In this instance, the unions have been coming under a lot of attack, as in criticism and oppression.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: > "real experts in being vague" - I *completely* agree.  I also harbor huge distrust for all politicians.  However, based on the context here (previous sentences, general flow of his speech), I really think he is being sympathetic to unions in this specific case.  So your initial answer fits here.  He probably meant "feet" not "heels".  Thanks again for being helpful.

Comment: @RoaringFish That also sounds like the probable explanation.  Thank you.

Comment: @Sabuncu: I think your question would be more "unambiguously answerable" if you included more background context. If *you* think Obama is expressing sympathy/support for unions, based on other things he says during the speech, perhaps you should include at least a summary of the contextual elements that lead you to this conclusion. But at the end of the day we're not looking at a standard usage, so we can't say what "it" means - only what *Obama* meant (or *might* have meant) when he used the words.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Again, I mostly agree with you. But one question: if something is not standard usage, does that disqualify it from being discussed here?  Thank you.

Comment: @Sabuncu: My instinct is to say Obama's usage is probably *deliberate/creative*, rather than erroneous (or reflecting a form with limited currency). On that basis it may well be Off Topic (primarily opinion-based) in much the same way as Lit Crit interpretation. But I haven't voted one way or the other yet. I'm waiting to see what others think. I'm not a mod, btw - and if I *were*, I do not think I would be anywhere near as good at the job as Andrew.

Comment: I removed the noise from the comments and edited the question to represent how I felt it ought have been edited in the first place.

Comment: This is an excellent question. What _is_ the provenance and more accurate meaning of the phrase?

Comment: @Mitch Thank you for your support.  The treatment I have received from the mod who's put the question on hold has absolutely ruined my day.  I no longer feel welcome at ELU as a low score member.

Comment: @Sabuncu: I think you took the advice of the mod the wrong way. He was just giving advice on how to make your question better and fit with local culture. Sometimes honest constructive criticism is taken as rudeness. I know this may sound too blunt, but you're not special. Meaning that no one is out to get you in particular. No knows you and so all we can go on is the content. And so that was what was being commented on, not you personally. No personal attack was intended. But it's the effect on you that matters not the intent. The mods are surely learning from this interaction.

Comment: @Mitch Your comments are all sound.  You are articulate and considerate and have my vote if you ever run for mod.

Comment: @Mitch Looks like I won't be able to fulfill my promise to you, as I have decided to leave the site. I want to thank you for treating me w/ respect.  But I feel this site overall is not a welcoming place for users like myself, based on my experience w/ the mod Andrew Leach and certain users such as J.R.

Comment: @Sabuncu I'm sorry to hear that you will leave. Andrew and J.R. are despite your feelings, considered both very fair, well-reasoned, and helpful. The other mods too. If it'll help, stay awhile and just read to get a feel for the place (and meta too). And compare with other sites. Then judge.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think that "back on their heels" means "in a defensive posture"; in boxing, it is almost impossible to take the offensive unless your weight is on your toes, pushing forward or at least dancing around. If your weight is back on your heels, you may be able to back away (that is, retreat) further, but you will not do so with much agility, and you won't even be in a position to counterpunch effectively. Roaring Fish's explanation above is generally correct, in my opinion.